How to take color pictures of documents so that the size and resolution is similar to the document scanned
I often take pictures of documents (e.g. passport, ID card, health insurance) with my phone. I then edit the picture in Gimp (rotate, crop, scale to about 1024x768 and save as png). The size is always above 1mB.
If I scan the same document the size is about 500kB (i.e. half of the picture) and the resolution is just as good.
Maybe this picture will help explain. It is a screenshot of a close-up of my passport. Left is the PDF, right is the editted picture I took with my phone.
The PDF has higher resolution (it seems to me) and only half the size.

So my problem is really the document size. But I want to ensure the resolution is readable.
As I do not have a scanner at home and the shop charges about Euro1 per scan, how can I edit my photographed documents to achieve scan quality and scan document size (I use linux, gimp, imagemagick, etc)?

The first thing to check is the size in pixels. On a scanner you can often pick a scan definition, from 15OPPI (low, but enough for web use) to 600PPI (very high, and usually totally unnecessary). For your passport (8.8*12.5cm) this means image of 0.4Mpx@15OPPI, or 1.5Mpx@300PPI, or 6Mpx@600PPI.
But if you fill the frame on your phone you produce an image of 12Mpix on a modern smartphone, which is already twice the size of a ultra-high quality scan.
You can bring back your image to size in two simple operations and make gimp do all the computations for you (assuming you have already rotate/cropped):
Change the image definition in Image > Print size

Resize the image in centimetres:

Result:

Then, export the image as JPEG, using a quality in the 85-90 range, that produces good compression without much quality loss (the 150PPI result above is 86K as a Q90 JPEG). A bonus point of this technique is that the print definition is stored in the JPEG so if the print utility abides to this the printout will be at the original size.

PNG compression doesn't work well on photos
There are many ways to store an image in a PDF but it the PDF is small, the PDF image is essentially a JPEG embedded in the PDF. There is no magic!


For me the explanation of this "effect" is:
PDF use internally JPEG (which are lossy compressible). PNG is lossless compressed. This lead to higher resolution, but smaller size of PDF file.
